# Java, Eclipse keep getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError openDMX

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, usb, wrapper

I tried downloading the open DMX java wrapped form [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opendmxjavajni/).  I'm using Eclipse as IDE. When I run the example I got the java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError openDMX.

So I googled the hell out of it and I found out that I had to define the build path of the dll file (from what I found this had to do with the driver for the usb device?)

I tried the following:
Definde the path in run configurations->vm arguments and then -Djava.library.path=dll

as was included in the readme. This gave the same exception

Then I found that I could define the build path. Right clicked the main folder in the file browser in eclipse.

Then properties->libraries->JRE system libraries->native library location

I browsed in the workspace for de dll folder and set the opendmx_example/dll as the native library location

Stil: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opendmx in java.library.path

Does somebody experience the same trouble or is it something that I'm doing wrong

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean project properties? If the DLL is 32 bit you have to run it on a 32 bit JRE.

Comment: Oke how can i check that?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/889267

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem and not founding any solution. Could you solve it? If yes, can you please tell me how?

Comment: Setting the native library location (Properties >> Java Build Path >> Libraries- >> JRE System Libraries >> Native Library Location) worked for me. I copied the opendmx.dll file to a "lib" folder within my project and used the option "workspace", selecting the "lib" folder.